# Deck Downloader

Tags: swift

This is my struct:

```
fileprivate struct DownloadDeck: Equatable{
    let uid: Int
    var publicOnly: Bool
    static func ==(lhs: DownloadDeck, rhs: DownloadDeck) -> Bool {
        return lhs.uid == rhs.uid
    }
}
```

I want to download a deck (60 cards) if publicOnly if false, and 8 cards if publicOnly is true. I now got two arrays of downloadDecks:

```
var downloadDecks = [DownloadDeck]()
var uniqueDownloadDecks = [DownloadDeck]()
```

`downloadDecks` get populated like this:

```
for deck in Engine.engineDeck.allDecks{
    downloadDecks.append(DownloadDeck(uid: deck.uid, publicOnly: !deck.availableForFree))
}

for deck in CurrentUser.ownedCards{
    downloadDecks.append(DownloadDeck(uid: deck.uid, publicOnly: false))
}
```

Now a deck can occur multiple times in downloadDecks with the same UID. I want to filter out the duplicate UIDs and if publicOnly is false in one of the duplicates, publicOnly should be set to false to the unique deck. This is my code to do that:

```
for deck in downloadDecks{
    if let existingDeck = uniqueDownloadDecks.first(where: {$0 == deck}){
        var mutableExistingDeck = existingDeck
        if existingDeck.publicOnly && !deck.publicOnly{
            mutableExistingDeck.publicOnly = false
        }
    }else{
        uniqueDownloadDecks.append(deck)
    }
}
```

Now I got two arrays which holds the same data. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You seem to be asking a question, this site is for code review. If you want to ask a question, please go to stackexchange.com

Comment: @Colea this IS stackexchange, and why can't i ask a question? there is literally a tab "questions"  if you scroll up, and a large button "Ask question"...

Comment: That is true. I made a typo. Go to stackOVERFLOW.com to ask a question. This site is for code review.

Comment: Don't worry, if your code is working (no known bugs) and is complete (not edited or shortened) then you're in the right place ;-) So, is it working and is it complete?

Comment: @Colea yea, this question is for code review. I am literally asking how to improve my code. Whatever.

Comment: @t3chb0t Yea, I am just asking how to improve my code.